# How to get youtube video html element from iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, youtube-data-api

I need to modify the video element of an *youtube embed iframe*.
when the website is loaded the **video element** exists inside the code but I can't query that element, Why?

Here is my code of Iframe :

```
<iframe 
width="560" 
height="315" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/OACVuteYdZU" 
frameborder="0" 
allow="accelerometer; 
autoplay; 
encrypted-media; 
allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "modify"?

Comment: `I can't query that element` assuming you mean that you want to access the content of the iframe using Javascript, then this is not possible in a cross-domain iframe for security reasons.

Comment: I need that video element to pass through web audio API so I need to query that element! are there any other ways to access that element? @NicoHaase

Comment: Thanks for the reply! @RoryMcCrossan